# what should keep in mind before providing work space for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

[This is how the workspace assign on an eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZY91.png)

My Web project run only when my project is at c:\Ampps\www\myProject but eclipse contains it on C:\Simple\workspace\myProject. My problem is I want to run project and the workspace is different. What is the things keep in mind before choosing the workspace. And what are the alternatives if the wrong workspace choosen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse does not require your projects to live under your workspace folder. Therefore you are allowed to have a project and workspace as you describe.

When creating a project, uncheck the default location checkbox in the wizard and select your truly desired location.

My only recommendation on workspace location is to have it on a local drive and don't have it as a sub directory of any project in your workspace.